# MongoDB with update queries, create and add item to list or increase item's counter

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document schema:

```
{
    date: dateValue
    items:
        [
            { name: 'a', counter: 4},
            { name: 'b', counter: 17},
            { name: 'aabbb', counter: 15},
            ...
        ]       
}
```

I would like to have an update query with upsert that creates the entire record if the record does not exist.
In addition, i want to check if a certain item exists on the list (by it's name),
if the item doesn't exist i want to add a new one to the list with counter = 1.
If the item exists raise the counter by 1.

Is there any way to do this query in with one update statment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Use the `{upsert:1}` flag on update to insert particular date document if it doesn't already exist.
2. Use `{$inc}` operator to increment your item values.  It turns out that if you increment a field that doesn't exist by 1 it will be created with value 1 (it's as if it existed with value 0).
3. You may not be able to get the above accomplished with the schema you currently have.  In order to increment a counter it has to be the name - i.e. "a":1, "b":17, etc.  You currently have it as key:"name", counter:"value" which means you can only update them with positional operator.  But positional operator requires that you match an element in order to successfully update it, so there goes the strategy to use `$inc`

So it looks like if you want to do this in a single update statement you would need to change your schema - only you can decide if that's the way to go since it may affect how your other reads and writes interact with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've already done the schema changes as you suggested since it was only solution I could find.